# can't debug my board (stm32f103) bluebill with atolic(trueStudio)?

Tags: debugging, openocd

I can't debug my stm32 bluebill board on trueStudio and getting this console error log so can't one help with this error?

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 5.1.0
Copyright (c) 2018, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting a server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Debugger connection lost.
Shutting down...
```

Comment: And what debugger are you using? Blue pill board doesn't have on board hardware for the debuging.

Comment: yes it doesn't have one but I am using st-link v2 for debugging and this error occurs when I am using eclipse for debugging also I notice in debug configuration it tries to connect to localhost at port 61234

Comment: Then please include that and other relevant info in your question (schematic, other tools?). Also explain what have you tried already and what worked, what didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue here was with the shared resource between the debugger peripheral pin and application pin that disables the peripheral on load so we need to reset all memory map and reset whole registers then debug free and solve the application issue with the debug peripheral pin